# Set a captive network without internet in raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, access-point, captiveportal

I want to open an html file I made in rpi3 on the web browser of my phone immediately as I connect to pi AP. My pi AP is not connected to the internet. Nodogsplash doesn't work without internet. Also this html page isn't a login or authentication page. Just a normal page with some buttons on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a working answer in [this](https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash/issues/154) github issue :

All you have to do is add the line:

```
address=/#/[ip address of your museum tour webserver]
```

to the config of `dnsmasq.conf`.